# how is it possible that the Toast no longer works?

Tags: android, toast

I'm a beginner, but I want to learn and I'm developing my first app!!I would also like to use the "toaster" function in the app. Unfortunately no longer works !!
Not only in my app, but no matter where I want to use it. Should I reinstall android studio?
Thank you, Stefan

Hi, no error message! Just not work!!
MainActivity:

```
package de.havadinagy.toaster_test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void info(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Only  Toastertest!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

activity_main :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:onClick="info"
        android:text="ToasterTest"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Would you please post the code for `Toast` and also the error message you are getting, so that we can check and revert.

Comment: Hi, no error message! Just not work!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

do try this

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 public void info(View view){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Only  Toastertest!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and change "info"